# HTTPS data over socket using HTTPS proxy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl

I am looking to send HTTPS data over HTTPS proxy connected via sockets.

I can send data over port 80 (in the CONNECT) through the proxy fine, however when I send data over port 443 (in the CONNECT), I usually get http errors. heres an example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established



HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Fri, 17 Dec 2021 22:39:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 220
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I fixed this by adding `Host: https://httpbin.org` in the headers rather than `Host: www.httpbin.org`, however now I receive:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established



HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Fri, 17 Dec 2021 22:49:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 122
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

No matter what I do I can't seem to get the server to respond correctly, am I missing a header? I was reading some other stackoverflow posts and some people mention that I need to double wrap the socket, however I am not too sure where to start.

Any information would be delightful.

I appreciate your help,

Thank you.

```py
# first way i tried
#from OpenSSL import SSL
#sslSocket = SSL.Connection(SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD), socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))

# second way i tried
import socket, ssl
sslSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))

# both of the above solutions work and end with the same result.

# CONNECT TO PROXY
sslSocket.connect(('remote_datacenter_proxy', 443))

# SEND CONNECT REQUEST
sslSocket.send(b'CONNECT httpbin.org:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nProxy-Authorization: Basic BASE_64_USERPASS\r\n\r\n')
response = sslSocket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(response)

# SEND GET REQUEST
sslSocket.send(b'GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: https://httpbin.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n')
response = sslSocket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
print(response)
```

Comment: You have to first connect the socket to the proxy with `do_handshake_on_connect=false`, then tell the proxy to `CONNECT` to the HTTPS server, **then initiate a TLS handshake with the HTTPS server** using `sslSocket.do_handshake()`, then finally send the HTTP request.  You are skipping the TLS step, so the request is not encrypted. You have to handshake with the HTTPS server, not with the proxy.

Comment: You also need to read() and parse the individual HTTP responses *properly* from both the proxy and the HTTPS server. A single `recv(1024)` for each one is not going to cut it. You need to follow the HTTP protocol correctly. That means reading the response line, the response headers, parsing the line and headers to determine the presence and format of a message body, and reading the body to its natural end. If you don't do that, you will corrupt your communications.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I appreciate your quick response, I will have to take a deeper dive on how everything works exactly. I might use a higher level library like pycurl. I am reading into https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.txt now. I tried to do `sslSocket.do_handshake()` but it returns `None`, however I think i am doing a handshake with the proxy and now the actual HTTPS server. I assumed that it would be more straightforward like working with HTTP :)

Comment: `ssl.wrap_socket()` has `do_handshake_on_connect=true` by default, you need to flip that.

Answer (score 0):

No clue if this is correct, but after some messing around I managed to come up with this, and it works.

```py
import socket, ssl

sslSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
# CONNECT TO PROXY
sslSocket.connect(('REMOTE_PROXY', 443))

# SEND GET REQUEST
sslSocket.send(b'GET https://api.ipify.org/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.ipify.org\r\nProxy-Authorization: Basic BASE64_USERPASS\r\n\r\n')
headers, body = sslSocket.recv(4096).decode(), sslSocket.recv(4096).decode()
print(headers, body)
```